# Is there a way to export more than 10000 records to AWS s3 from Google reporting analytics API daily?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have a GA 360 view that gets decent amount of traffic daily and i want to export the hit level data (using GA_client_id) to the aws s3 server. the limitation here is that GA API allows only 10000 records a day. someone suggested that if we put the GA_client_id in a custom dimension, the limit would not apply. is it true? please let me know if there is another solution to export more than 10000 records for a single view per day. please note that this will be a single query that will auto run daily at a specific time.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 10000 records a day.

Correction 10000 **requests** per day per view.  A request response can include millions of records (rows)

Comment: so this means there would be no problem exporting more than 10000 records from a single daily export request?

Comment: assuming that by records you mean rows.  There is no issue with that.

Comment: Thank you so much. i think i have to test it out after setting up the project.